# MySQL how to compare 2 dates and return 1 of the specific outputs based on its return value?

Tags: mysql

This is my goal:

- Compare 2 dates, today's date and end date e.g. 2020/02/04 to 2021/02/03
- Return total number of days based from above. e.g. the above is 365 days
- If statement - If total number of days is less than 50% of 365 days return value of `Reject` if it's in region between `51% - 75%` then return value is `Caution`.. if it's above `76%` return value is `accept`

This is what I got to so far:

```
select datediff('2021-02-03', curdate());
```

The output is `365` days.

How can I place the 3 outputs mentioned above into 1 query? - or 3 different ones

Comment: you need to write a procedure

Comment: @salsinga I'll take a look

Comment: @98Ed you need to write when case for it

Comment: There is no requirement for a procedure here

Comment: I don't really see what this has to do with the storage and retrieval of data.

Comment: Remember, MySQL is not some kind of panacea. It's great for the storage and retrieval of relational data. Consider handling other problems elsewhere.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the comment. I needed this query to be written from another program to retrieve out of MySQL.

Comment: There is a function to use 'MySQL Execute query` - instead of the date provided in example. I will place a variable that is formatted like this `%Date%`. This then will finish my project off :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement for this situation. Based on your explanation here is sample for you.

```
SET @threshold = 365;
SET @date_diff = datediff('2020-02-28', curdate());
select @date_diff diff, @threshold `limit`, @threshold * 0.5 limit_50, @threshold * 0.75 limit_75, 
case
    when @date_diff <=  (@threshold * 0.5) then 'REJECT'
    when (@date_diff > (@threshold * 0.5)) and (@date_diff <= (@threshold * 0.75))  then 'CAUTION'
    ELSE 'ACCEPT'
end as status
;
```

Change your condition and outputs according to your need. Play with it Here - https://paiza.io/projects/28mhUtOmP4HiVe8YDDTo9Q?language=mysql

Answer (score 0):

`set @dt_comp='2021-02-03';
  select (case when datediff(@dt_comp, curdate())/365 <= 0.5 then 'Reject' 
             when datediff(@dt_comp, curdate())/365 >=0.51  and datediff('2021-02-03', curdate())/365 <=0.75  then 'Caution'
             when datediff(@dt_comp, curdate())/365 >0.75   then 'Accepted'  end) as descr_status;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sql to do this

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF('2019-10-30', Curdate()) > 365/2 THEN "Reject"
    WHEN DATEDIFF('2019-10-30', Curdate()) < 365/4 THEN "Accept"
    ELSE "Caution"
END AS result;
```